# How to display list of string with double quote separated by comma in Razor page c#?

Tags: c#, string, asp.net-core, razor

```
             labels: [@foreach (var item in new string[]{"ONE","TWO","THREE","FOUR","FIVE","SIX","SEVEN","EIGHT","NINE","TEN"})
             {
                @item
             }]
```

With this code I am able to get result as `ONETWOTHREEFOURFIVESIXSEVENEIGHTNINETEN`, The expected result i want to get inside label is `"ONE","TWO","THREE","FOUR","FIVE","SIX","SEVEN","EIGHT","NINE","TEN"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `String.Format`, change your code as follows:

```
labels: [@foreach (var item in new string[]{"ONE","TWO","THREE","FOUR","FIVE","SIX","SEVEN","EIGHT","NINE","TEN"})
{
    @String.Format("\"{0}\"{1}", item,!item.Equals("TEN")?",":"")
}
```

Comment: The result is still not as expected```&quot;ONE&quot;,&quot;TWO&quot;,&quot;THREE&quot;,&quot;FOUR&quot;,&quot;FIVE&quot;,&quot;SIX&quot;,&quot;SEVEN&quot;,&quot;EIGHT&quot;,&quot;NINE&quot;,&quot;TEN&quot;```

Comment: I ran my code, and I got the same result as you expected. What is your output?

Comment: This is my result in Chrome ```labels: [&quot;ONE&quot;,&quot;TWO&quot;,&quot;THREE&quot;,&quot;FOUR&quot;,&quot;FIVE&quot;,&quot;SIX&quot;,&quot;SEVEN&quot;,&quot;EIGHT&quot;,&quot;NINE&quot;,&quot;TEN&quot;,], ```

Comment: it seems that your browser doesn't decode your `&quot`, add @Html.Raw if you want it to be parsed as html

Comment: @Html.Raw(String.Format("&quot;{0}&quot;{1}", item,!item.Equals("TEN")?",":""))